# How to define latitude & longitude instead of address in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am displaying Map in my Application.I have added the code below and now the map is displaying correctly for particular city name. My Problem is i need to fetch location by using latitude and longitude of a particular city.

I don't want any new code.  Is it possible the get the latitude and longitude values within this code itself by pass @item.Latitude@item.Longitude  instead of @item.city

```
<div class="gMapsCanvas" data-address="@item.city"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var GoogleMap = function ga(canvas, address) {
                // debugger;
                var _parent = this;

                //this.location = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

                var options =
                {
                    center: this.location,
                    zoom: 11,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControlOptions:
                    {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
                    },
                    streetViewControl: false
                };

                this.map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        return;

                    _parent.location = results[0].geometry.location;

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map: _parent.map,
                        position: _parent.location
                    });

                    _parent.resize();
                });
            };

            GoogleMap.prototype.resize = function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, "resize");

                this.map.setCenter(this.location);
            }

            var Maps = function (classes) {
                var _parent = this;

                this.maps = new Array();

                classes.each(function () {
                    _parent.maps.push(new GoogleMap($(this).get(0), $(this).attr("data-address")));
                });
            };

            Maps.prototype.resize = function () {
                for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.maps.length; cnt++) {
                    this.maps[cnt].resize();
                }
            };

            var maps;

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".tiptext").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).children(".description").show();

            maps = new Maps($(".gMapsCanvas"));

        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).children(".description").hide();

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try { 'latlng': latitude + ',' + longitude } instead of { 'address': address }.

I didn't test it but it seems to work according to googlemap webservice api : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to display Google Maps in your browser.
but the two most easy and good ways are:
 1. to Use Goggle MAP API https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en
 2. Google Polymer as shown below:

```
     <!-- Polyfill Web Components support for older browsers -->
<script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<!-- Import element -->
<link rel="import" href="components/google-map/google-map.html">

<!-- Use element -->
<google-map latitude="37.790" longitude="-122.390"></google-map>
```

Comment: where can i get webcomponents-lite.min.js and google-map.html ?

Comment: Plese click on the above link

Comment: is there any demo for your code that you mentioned above